# How to find the biggest difference in an SQL column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following information:

Table: bar

```
minute | beer
1      | 48
2      | 24
3      | 92
4      | 17
5      | 38
6      | 64
```

I want to know what or where the biggest difference is in the column beer. By manually seeing it with my own eyes, it's between minute 3 and 4, but how can I do this in SQL?

I had something in mind:

```
Select minute, count(beer) as spike
from bar
where ???
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Are you looking for a difference between consecutive items? For example, if I added a line `7, 1000`, would the biggest difference be 64 to 1000, or 17 to 1000?

Comment: Do you mean difference between two consecutive rows or overall = min/max?

Comment: @juergend MySQL.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 17 to 1000 in this case.

Comment: select min and max. that will give biggest difference. If you are interested in getting minute,select minute where beer = min/max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need nested aggregation:

```
select max(spike) - min(spike)
from
 (  -- count per minute
    Select minute, count(beer) as spike
    from bar
    group by minute
 ) as dt
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql `MAX()` and `MIN()` functions to get highest and lowest values.

```
SELECT MIN(beer) AS lowestBeer, MAX(beer) as highestBeer
FROM bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be:

```
select max(beer) - min(beer)
from bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the order does not matter, you can do it with a self-join:

```
SELECT a.minute AS from_minute, b.minute AS to_minute, a.beer, b.beer
FROM bar a
CROSS JOIN bar b
ORDER BY a.beer-b.beer DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This would yield a row describing from what minute to what minute you have the biggest difference, along with the corresponding values of `beer`.